Is Bash slow or am I doing something wrong?
Recently I've had a need in going through the logs in my Minecraft Server. I needed to unpack several gzipped log files and collapse them into one huge log. And then I'd use grep to seek for useful info (however that's how I decided to do that).
So I've decided to write a bash script:
  dir="/home/minecraft/spigot-1.20.2/logs"

  logs=$(ls $dir)

  start=$SECONDS
  sum=""

  for log in $logs
  do
      s=$SECONDS
      log_date=$(echo $log | cut -b 1-10)
      unzipped_log="$(zcat -f $dir/$log | sed -e "s/\[Async Chat Thread - #[0-9]\+\/INFO]: //" -e "s/^/$log_date /g")"$'\n'
      while read -r line
      do
          echo "$line"
      done <<< "$unzipped_log"
      echo The file $log $(du -h $dir/$log) processed in $(($SECONDS - $s))
  done

  s=$SECONDS
  last="$(cat $dir/latest.log | sed -e "s/\[Async Chat Thread - #[0-9]\+\/INFO]: //")"$'\n'
  date_today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  while read -r line
  do
      echo "$date_today $line"
  done <<< "$last"
  echo The file latest.log processed in $(($SECONDS - $s))

  echo Script worked in $(($SECONDS-$start)) seconds

After launching source sum_logs.sh | tac > all_logs.txt the timing was 60 seconds.
I then rewrote the code in Python:
  import os, gzip, time, re
  from datetime import datetime

  dir = "/home/minecraft/spigot-1.20.2/logs"

  start = time.time()
  time.sleep(1)

  logs = os.listdir(dir)

  for log in logs:
      log_path = os.path.join(dir, log)
      log_date = log[:10]
      try:
          with gzip.open(log_path, 'rt') as f:
              for line in f.readlines():
                  line = re.sub(r'\[Async Chat Thread - #\d+\/INFO]: ', '', line)
                  print(log_date, line.replace('\n', ''))
      except:
          with open(log_path, 'r') as f:
              for line in f.readlines():
                  line = re.sub(r'\[Async Chat Thread - #\d+\/INFO]: ', '', line)
                  print(log_date, line.replace('\n', ''))

  elapsed = round(time.time() - start)

  print(f'Script worked in {elapsed} seconds')

The timing is 9 seconds.
I understand that bash is slower than Python. But I had no idea that the difference is 6x. Is bash really so slow or is there a way to speed up my code?
Edit.
dir="/home/minecraft/spigot-1.20.2/logs"

start=$SECONDS
sum=""

for f in $dir/*
do
    s=$SECONDS
    log=$(echo $f | cut -b 36-)
    log_date=$(echo $log | cut -b 1-10)
    unzipped_log="$(zcat -f $dir/$log | sed -e "s/\[Async Chat Thread - #[0-9]\+\/INFO]: //" -e "s/^/$log_date /g")"$'\n'
    echo "$unzipped_log"
    echo The file $log $(du -h $dir/$log) processed in $(($SECONDS - $s))
done

s=$SECONDS
date_today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
last="$(cat $dir/latest.log | sed -e "s/\[Async Chat Thread - #[0-9]\+\/INFO]: //" -e "s/^/$date_today /g")"$'\n'
echo $last
echo The file latest.log processed in $(($SECONDS - $s))

echo Script worked in $(($SECONDS-$start)) seconds

The above code runs at 23 seconds!
The main problem was in nested loops I think.
I had no idea that I could use s/^/$date/g.
Edit 2.
dir="/home/minecraft/spigot-1.20.2/logs"

start=$SECONDS
sum=""

for f in $dir/*
do
    s=$SECONDS
    log=$(echo $f | cut -b 36-)
    log_date=$(echo $log | cut -b 1-10)
    zcat -f $dir/$log | sed -e "s/\[Async Chat Thread - #[0-9]\+\/INFO]: //" -e "s/^/$log_date /g"
    echo The file $log $(du -h $dir/$log) processed in $(($SECONDS - $s))
done

s=$SECONDS
date_today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
cat $dir/latest.log | sed -e "s/\[Async Chat Thread - #[0-9]\+\/INFO]: //" -e "s/^/$date_today /g"
echo The file latest.log processed in $(($SECONDS - $s))

echo Script worked in $(($SECONDS-$start)) seconds

Okay, now it's 5 seconds :0.
Deleted unnecessary variables, as suggested. I'm in big surprise...

You are doing something wrong, but it's not the source of your problem: don't use ls in scripts

The slowness seems to be a variant of Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?

@tripleee
I see, thanks for advice. Each file here is either 2024-05-09-1.log.gz or latest.log
So there's no problem with ls in my case, I think. But good to know.

unzipped_log="$(zcat ... | sed ...)"; while/read ... echo ... done <<< "$unzipped_log" could all be replaced with zcat ... | sed -e ... -e "s/^/$log_date /"; similar for the 2nd loop

in the 2nd loop you have echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d) $line" which is invoking an (expensive) subhell to obtain the current date; big performance hit here because that subshell is invoked for every pass thru the loop; even worse, each subshell is returning the same exact thing; you would be better off invoking that subshell once before the loop (storing the result in a variable) and then referencing the variable in the echo (better yet, add an additional sed -e clause to preference all lines with $last_date - see previous comment about rewriting 1st loop)

@markp-fuso
Oh, nice! I love the shortcut. Is it like you replacing the start of a line ^ with date? I thought it would be like s/^/&$log_date/. But your variant does work)

since we're talking about the start of the line the & is redundant (in this case); regardless ... when in doubt, try it out

@markp-fuso
About the second loop, I see the mistake. However the loop operates only on a small file of current log. So it may take about 5-10 extra seconds at worst. But the rest 50...

do you have timings on how long it takes to process each file? if not then add some timings (eg, date before processing each file; difference between 2x samplings of $SECONDS, etc); those subshell invocations (to obtain the same date result) are expensive in terms of timings; depending on number of lines and your OS ... those $(date ...) calls could be causing the last log file processing to represent an outsized portion of the total time

@markp-fuso wow, I didn't know about $SECONDS. Remade everything with it. However the performance is the same: 65 seconds.
I've added timings to files. And most of them are processed immidiatelly. While there are some of them with 27/25/7 seconds. Those are big files 400kb+ (other are ~4kb). Updated the code in question.

What's the point of the while read loop? You could just echo "$unzipped_log" with much, much less overhead, or let your zcat | sed | ... pipeline write direct to stdout and never store the content in an unzipped_log variable at all.

As someone who writes a great deal of both bash and Python (among other languages), I'd consider bash code that's 1/6th the performance of equivalent Python quite competitive. People who make the usual mistakes (spawning unnecessary subshells or external executables in a tight inner loop, for example) often make shell scripts more than 100x slower than equivalent Python; as it is, you're doing some moderately inefficient things, but (for the most part, excluding the unnecessary while read line; do echo "$line"; done loop) only doing them once per file, not once per line.

That said, I'd like to urge you not to go down the "my files' names all fit this pattern so code that incorrectly processes them is fine" rabbithole. The worst data loss event I've ever been personally present for was caused by someone making that assumption -- then a new program was added creating files in the same directory, and a C library used by that Python program ("memory-safe", ha!) had a buffer overflow that dumped random garbage into the string used for filenames.

The net result was that we got a filename with a * in it surrounded by spaces, and when a sloppily-written shell script tried to delete that file, it deleted all of our backups used for billing support. That's not a place you want to be; Just Say No to unquoted expansions to try to treat strings in shell variables as if they were arrays.

(also, avoid cat foo | ... in favor of <foo ... or ... <foo -- not a big difference when ... is sed, but when it's something like tail or sort or wc -c that can optimize when given a seekable file descriptor you can miss out on very real performance gains).

(and make a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ -- nothing it'll find that's obviously performance-centric, but plenty of little correctness optimizations available).

ls $dir is going to pick up latest.log so you'll end up processing latest.log twice, yes? is that what you want?

Thank you all for support! I think the code may be optimized further, but I'm glad that difference is already x2.5 not x6

@markp-fuso That's not happening, latels.log only once

from the latest update - unzipped_log="$(zcat ... | sed ...)" ; echo "$unzipped_log" - why incur the overhead of a) a subshell to invoked zcat | sed and b) storing the entire results in memory just to echo to stdin the next line of code; as already pointed out in comments and the accepted answer ... eliminate these overheads by replacing these 2 lines of code with the single line zcat | sed; same goes for the last="$(zcat | sed)" ; echo "$last"

@markp-fuso  It wasn't obvious for me, that variables would be such a performance killer :0. Thanks!

Think about operations in terms of how they're implemented. Hooking a program to to a FIFO, reading its output from that FIFO, and then writing it back out again -- instead of just writing the output direct to the place you want it to be in the first place -- is going to be overhead in any language.

Mind, what's even worse than that is that echo isn't guaranteed to write your contents byte-for-byte identical to the original values, but that's an entirely different topic. (When you care about reliability, use printf instead -- see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819).

not a big performance issue but the cat is unnecessary here - cat $dir/latest.log | sed -e ... -e ... - since sed is capable of reading directly from the file; instead consider sed -e ... -e ...  "$dir/latest.log"  (also get in the habit of wrapping variable references in double quotes (run a test to see what happens if dir contains spaces and you don't use double quotes); in your 2nd script you have echo $last but if $last has embedded linefeeds (\n) then take a look at the output diff between echo $last and echo "$last"

you should be able to trim some more time off by replacing the inefficient $(echo ... | cut ...) constructs; same issue as has already been beat to death ... eliminate unnecessary subshells, especially inside a loop; I've added a section to the (accepted) answer with more details. eliminating those additional 4 subshells (for each pass through the loop) should shave a bit more off the total time; fwiw you can get a bit more granular timing with time for f in "$dir"/*; do ... done

With the latest update to the question it appears comments are not making enough sense sooooo, iterating through suggestions ...
unzipped_log="$(zcat -f $dir/$log | sed -e "s/\[Async Chat Thread - #[0-9]\+\/INFO]: //" -e "s/^/$log_date /g")"
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done <<< "$unzipped_log"

Eliminate storing all of the zcat ... | sed ... results in a variable and instead feed directly to the while/read loop:
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done < <(zcat -f $dir/$log | sed -e "s/\[Async Chat Thread - #[0-9]\+\/INFO]: //" -e "s/^/$log_date /g")"

But since the only thing the loop is doing is 'read a line, echo a line, read a line, echo a line' we can just eliminate the loop:
zcat -f $dir/$log | sed -e "s/\[Async Chat Thread - #[0-9]\+\/INFO]: //" -e "s/^/$log_date /g"


Same exact code design can be used to replace the 2nd while/read loop.
NOTE: move $date_today into the sed script just like was done for $log_date.

The construct var1=$(echo $var2 | cut -b start-length) is overly complicated and incurs two additional (expensive) subshells.  The fact this contruct is used twice inside a while loop amplifies the performance degradation.
With bash 4.2+ we can make use of the builtin substring capability:
${var:start:len}

Keep in mind bash position numbering starts with 0 so if you start with x=123456 and want the first 3 characters: ${x:1:3} => 234 while ${x:0:3} => 123
Using this info we can modify OP's current code as follows:
### replace this:

log=$(echo $f | cut -b 36-)
log_date=$(echo $log | cut -b 1-10)

### with this:

log="${f:35}"
log_date="${log:0:10}"

NOTE: I'm assuming OP is dealing with single-byte characters so cut -b and cut -c would be equivalent; if OP is dealing with multi-byte characters then the replacement code may be a bit more involved

The logs=$(ls $dir) / for log in $logs construct could be improved upon but it would help to have a sample of the actual filenames in the $dir directory.

Rantings in the comments apart- keep in mind that when you do sed ... in Bash, for example, you are running an entire subprocess - an OS backed subprocess, with a lot of overhead - while in Python, a function call will just run a couple opcodes.  The same goes for ls, and almost all "commands" but for a few that are built-in. There are exceptions that had been made a built-in over time as  echo.
People proficient in Bash will usually know how to avoid these traps, and just don't call subprocess in loops. Hence people in the comments telling you to "never use ls in a script".
On the other hand a language like Python has a standard syntax will run everything in a single process, and if one needs to run something in a external process, that is quite explicit - function calls will take up to 1000x less OS resources than an external process running.

echo is builtin, so unless someone forces /usr/bin/echo it doesn't fall into the same category as ls or sed. (Still, bash's built-in echo is less efficient than Python's print() or sys.stdout.write() because it has to flush after every operation, whereas write or print in Python can defer flushing when stdout is fully buffered).

Thanks for the info - I am updating that.

It being a subprocess isn't the reason for avoiding ls in scripts.
